# Add and fill tabs dynamically on JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to create tabs and fill them each in turn dynamically but I can't fill more than one. I did some research and realized that putting the same FlowPane in several places was impossible, but I wonder how to do it then. I have tried several encapsulation methods and either it generates an error or the result remains the same. 
Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
public class ButtonController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private Button bubu;
    @FXML
    private Button bb;
    @FXML
    private TabPane tp;

    List<Button> buttonlist = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Tab> tablist = new ArrayList<>();

    Main parent;

    public void setParent(Main main) {
        this.parent=main;
    }

    @FXML
    public void action() {
        try {
            Connection conn = bddUtil.dbConnect();
            tablist.clear();
            buttonlist.clear();
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select nom, prix from produit");
            ResultSet res = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select nom from type_produit");
            while (res.next()) {
                Tab tab = new Tab(res.getString("nom"));
                FlowPane flowp = new FlowPane();
                tablist.add(tab);
                tab.setContent(flowp);
                flowp.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Button btn = new Button(rs.getString("nom") + "\n" + rs.getInt("prix") + "€");
                    btn.setPrefSize(200, 100);
                    btn.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
                    btn.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override 
                        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                            String txtBtn = btn.getText();
                        }
                    });
                    buttonlist.add(btn);
                }
                flowp.getChildren().addAll(buttonlist);
            }
            tp.getTabs().addAll(tablist);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("err: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class HandlerBtn1 implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop makes sure the first result set in exhausted after filling the first tab. You should get multiple `FlowPane`s in multiple tabs, but all the buttons go into the first tab... You could use a single query and a `Map<String, Tab>` storing tabs by values in the `nom` column...

Comment: Note that `VARCHAR` (or similar) may not be the best column for a foreign key and duplicating data in 2 tables is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I didn't understand correctly, how can I display all the buttons in all the tabs? I don't know Map well yet so I don't really see how to do it... 

I had thought about making an inner join in my sql request but I ended up with as many tabs as buttons, Map could fix that?

I have two tables one that contains food names and one that references their type (like eggs&bacon -> breakfast), so it is necessary to have two tables, right?

Comment: inner join be like : select produit.nom, prix, type_produit.nom from produit inner join type_produit on produit.idType=type_produit.idType

Comment: At the risk of sounding insolent, I think you're trying to do too much. Creating a GUI is already a relatively advanced topic, but trying to do so when you lack basic familiarity with fundamental data structures such as `Map` will only make the process more difficult. On top of that you don't appear to be familiar with either JDBC or SQL yet you're trying to integrate those technologies with a UI technology you also don't appear to be familiar with.

Comment: I understand one can only get better with practice, but may I suggest learning each technology separately so that you're at least comfortable with each before trying to integrate them? In my opinion, understanding SQL will make using JDBC much easier to reason about; you should also be quite comfortable with "everyday Java" before learning a UI toolkit. Also, note that UI code may be different than what you're used to—see [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) and the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Comment: Thank you @fabian I finally succeeded with the Map
Slaw, I have to do everything at the same time, I'm a student and I have to return this project in a short time... Thank you, your answer will help me a lot to continue my project, I didn't know that we could process the database data in a different file, I will inform myself as soon as possible on all you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it, it may not be the best way but it works so I leave it here if someone has the same problem!

```
    @FXML
private TabPane tp;

List<Button> buttonlist = new ArrayList<>();
List<Tab> tablist = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String, Tab> map= new HashMap<>();

ArrayList<String> nomProduits = new ArrayList<>();

@FXML
public void action() {
    try {
        Connection conn = bddUtil.dbConnect();
        tablist.clear();
        buttonlist.clear();
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select produit.nom, prix, type_produit.nom from produit inner join type_produit on produit.idType=type_produit.idType");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Tab tab = new Tab(rs.getString("type_produit.nom"));
            map.put(rs.getString("type_produit.nom"), tab);
            nomProduits.add(rs.getString("produit.nom"));
        }

        for (Tab tab : map.values()) {  
            FlowPane fp = new FlowPane();
            tab.setOnSelectionChanged(new EventHandler<Event>() {
                public void handle(Event event) {
                    fp.getChildren().clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < nomProduits.size(); i++) {
                        Button btnPlat = new Button(nomProduits.get(i));
                        fp.getChildren().add(btnPlat);  
                    }
                    tab.setContent(fp);

                }
            });
        }
tp.getTabs().addAll(map.values());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```